# VBA Code for Null value to Zero

Tags: vba, null

How do I modify these functions so that Null values are returned as Zero?

```
Function MinOfList(ParamArray varValues()) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer        'Loop controller.
    Dim varMin As Variant   'Smallest value found so far.

    varMin = Null           'Initialize to null

    For i = LBound(varValues) To UBound(varValues)
        If IsNumeric(varValues(i)) Or IsDate(varValues(i)) Then
            If varMin <= varValues(i) Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                varMin = varValues(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MinOfList = varMin
End Function

Function MaxOfList(ParamArray varValues()) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer        'Loop controller.
    Dim varMax As Variant   'Largest value found so far.

    varMax = Null           'Initialize to null

    For i = LBound(varValues) To UBound(varValues)
        If IsNumeric(varValues(i)) Or IsDate(varValues(i)) Then
            If varMax >= varValues(i) Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                varMax = varValues(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MaxOfList = varMax
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

Per Brad's comment, this solution will only work in Microsoft Access.

A cheap way out is to use the nz function

```
NZ(VariableName, 0)
```

End of the MinOfList Function: `MinOfList = NZ(varMin, 0)`

End of the MaxOfList Function: `MaxOfList = NZ(varMax, 0)`

Here's a quick Nz implementation to mimic NZ's functionality:

```
Public Function Nz( Value As Variant, ValueIfNull As Variant ) As Variant
    Nz = IIf(IsNull(Value), ValueIfNull, Value)
End Function
```

Comment: where would I add that?  thanks for help; using public code to try to accomplish my mission here.

Comment: @user3574211 I added where to the answer

Comment: This is your suggestion:   MinOfList = Nz(varMin, 0). Tried and not working.

Comment: `Nz` is part of the Access application library. If you are using Excel this won't work without adding a reference to Access

Comment: @Brad I hadn't known that actually, I thought it was part of all of the office programs. I'll note it in my answer.

Comment: Elias - its not returning the Null value as a zero.

Comment: @user3574211 The answer has been updated to work in other office applications. You can create a function that mimics the NZ functions capabilities, as transcribed above.

Comment: any thoughts on this question: instead of the smallest value, looking to choose the 2nd smallest?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371605/small-large-formula-convert-to-acess-vba-calculated-field-query

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the `varMin` and `varMax` objects with an `If` statement. Here's how to check in the `MinOfList` function:

```
If varMin = Null Then
    MinOfList = 0
Else
    MinOfList = varMin
End If
```

Comment: Or `MinOfList = IIf(IsNull(varMin), 0, varMin)`.  (Check to make sure that `If VarMin = Null` evaluates to something other than `Null`. When I test it, `?VarMin = Null` returns `Null`, not a boolean).

Comment: Dan, where would do I place your suggested code in the original code above? Thx

Comment: You would want to replace the last statement in each function, where the return value (i.e. `MinOfList` or `MaxOfList`) is assigned

Comment: @DavidZemens great idea, love learning about techniques that work... Always want to expand the skillset haha!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answering your question, but I found this while troubleshooting my own application.  I'm assuming that you are trying to get this working in Excel.  Other users have pointed out that Excel VBA does not recognize Nz().  I was able to work around this by using an ordinary Excel SUM() formula.  The key was to use the command Application.Evaluate() to run the function.

`sumBreakout = Application.Evaluate("SUM(J6:Y6)")`

For what its worth, this allowed me to total up several cells in Excel, regardless if it had a NULL value or the expected integer value.