# Small Large Formula Convert to Acess VBA Calculated Field Query

Tags: ms-access, vba, expression

I am trying to convert the following excel formula to a Calculated Field in Access.  Using Expressions or combination of a user defined expression with VBA code. any help appreciated! And appreciate any thoughts about data normalization, however this is not the issue. Thx

`IF(SMALL(T319:V319,2)>6,SMALL(T319:V319,1),IF(SMALL(T319:V319,2)=0,LARGE(T319:V319,1),SMALL(T319:V319,2)`

Cells T319 - V319 are fields in each record generated by a data query generated. call them A,B,C for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I presort the data so that from largest to smallest, the three values are represented by the letters I, J, and K.  This means J is `SMALL(T319:V319,2)`, K is `SMALL(T319:V319,1)` and I is `LARGE(T319:V319,1)`.

**UPDATE: fixed the pseudocode and final section of the function.  I misread the nested IFs of the Excel formula :P**

The pseudo-code would be:

```
If J > 6 Then
    return K
ElseIf J = 0 Then
    return I
Else
    return J
```

Are you sure this is what you want?

If so, you could make a VBA function as follows:

```
Public Function GetVal(A As Variant, B As Variant, C As Variant)
    Dim I As Variant
    Dim J As Variant
    Dim K As Variant

    'Sort the three values so A, B, C becomes sorted largest to smallest as I, J, K
    If A > B Then
        If A > C Then
            I = A
            If B > C Then
                J = B
                K = C
            Else 'C > B
                J = C
                K = B
            End If
        Else 'C > A
            I = C
            J = A
            K = B
        End If
    Else 'B > A
        If B > C Then
            I = B
            If A > C Then
                J = A
                K = C
            Else 'C > A
                J = C
                K = A
            End If
        Else 'C > B
            I = C
            J = B
            K = A
        End If
    End If

    'Use I, J, K to find the result
    If J > 6 Then
        GetVal = K
    ElseIf J = 0 Then
        GetVal = I
    Else
        GetVal = J
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I, J, K may not always presort so that I is largest, J is 2nd smallest and K is smallest.  Based on your proposed solution, not sure how to proceed, but thanks for your insight.

Comment: @user3574211 The way the Excel "SMALL" function works is that for array ARR and integer K, `SMALL(ARR, K)` returns the Kth smallest value of the array ARR.  If you have an array of three things `SMALL(ARR, 2)` will ALWAYS return the median element of the three, "LARGE" works the inverse way so `LARGE(ARR, 1)` will ALWAYS return the largest, and `SMALL(ARR, 1)` will ALWAYS return the smallest.  Thus the sorting of A, B, C into a list of largest to smallest...

Comment: @user3574211 and just so you know, I realize that the data you input into the function is not sorted.  That's why I perform the sort as the first half of the function.  A, B, C are your inputs, then I sort them so that I is the largest of the three, J is the middle, and K is the smallest of the three.  That way I can match the functionality of the comparisons as noted at the top of my answer.

Comment: @user3574211 If you REALLY want, I could provide implementations of the function `SMALL` and the function `LARGE` for Access, but it would require a sorting algorithm.  If you want a function that does EXACTLY the same thing as your Excel formula, this is it.  The reason it is so large is that Access doesn't natively have a LARGE or SMALL function.

Comment: What I am saying is when I perform a sort columns, which has +4K records, A-C will not always translate to I,J,K in that order.  Therefore this will be a jumbled output.             Therefore, I like your third response. Do you have this in a VBA code to implement?

Comment: "If you want a function that does EXACTLY the same thing as your Excel formula, this is it. The reason it is so large is that Access doesn't natively have a LARGE or SMALL function."  - YES, thanks!

Comment: The function in my answer sorts the three columns for you, on the fly.  All you need to do is provide the three colums of data in any order to the function.  It will spit back out the one that meets the criteria you set out in your Excel formula.  Give this function some testing if you would like to verify that it matches what you currently do.